# Cartoon where characters would fight with capsule gauntlets that shoot out small creatures

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I'm pretty sure that this cartoon is American and kind of old. I think it used to show on Disney?

The first thing that comes to mind is that the main character is discovering his past I think. In the world, people fight with these sort of capsule gauntlets which allow them to shoot out these small creatures that fight mid-air before going back into the capsule. They transform when released.

One episode shows the main character trying to save these creatures because the villain is corrupting and using their power for the worse things.

Comment: If you have a second work to identify you should ask it as a separate question else this would be too broad and get closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A newer (2012-2016) cartoon that might match this description is [Slugterra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slugterra).  It was shown on Disney XD.

> In the world, people fight with these sort of capsule gauntlets which
>   allow them to shoot out these small creatures that fight mid-air
>   before going back into the capsule. They transform when released.

People fight with slugs, which are "kept in special cylinder-shaped cases called slug shells."  When fired, they transform into Velocimorphs or Megamorphs.  If two slugs are fired simultaneously and intersect, they battle, as shown in this example:

They can be picked up and re-capsuled or, if they like their 'slinger, they'll return to them voluntarily.

> the villain is corrupting and using their power for the worse things.

The villian is "the nefarious Dr. Thaddius Blakk and his ghoul slugs."  The red-tinged slug shown in the video above is a Ghoul Slug; Blakk has a way of corrupting slugs and turning them into ghouls.

> the main character is discovering his past I think.

The main character ("Eli Shane") is attempting to follow in his father's footsteps,  and perhaps to find his father, and has a diary or letters from his father that reflect the past - my memory is vague here, but I think it could easily be mistaken for "discovering his past."

Comment: Oh. My. Gosh..! Thank you so much!!! This is definitely the one!! \owo/

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description of fighting by shooting small creatures, this might be *[Kiba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiba_(TV_series))*.

> Zed, a 15-year-old boy who lives in a city called "Calm", is frustrated by his current situation in life; he feels that somewhere out there is a place where he can live more fully. One day, at the invitation of a mysterious wind, he dives into a space-time crevasse (portal), seeking the answers that might be there. Riding on the wind, he is transported to a war-torn world where magic users called "Shard Casters" fight endlessly with each other, using spells in the form of marble-like "Shards". He is transported to a country known as Templar.
>
> With the power of the Shards, the Shard Casters are able to use spells and control monsters called "Spirits". Fascinated by that power, Zed aims to become a Shard Caster. However, he still doesn't know that residing in his body is "Amil Gaoul", a mighty Spirit with the power to influence the world's future. Amil Gaoul is one of the "Key Spirits" that, when together with the other Key Spirits, can destroy or save the world. There are a total of six Key Spirits: Amil Gaoul, Pronimo, Sachura, Monadi, Dynamis and Shadin.
>
> Zed undergoes countless trials in order to find out who he really is and what is most important to him.

Found by browsing the Tvtropes [Mons](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Mon) page.

Comment: This wasn't the show that I was looking for but thank you for answering. I'll be sure to check out this anime!

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for this show for 8 years. The name is Monsuno.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please [edit] your answer to explain why you think this is the answer.